# How can I toggle extra buttons in the navigation bar for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, slide

I currently have a navigation bar that is getting a little bulky. In the image below, the search button displays a search bar, which also brings up a cancel button with it. What I would like to do here is have one button that slides in/displays the current right bar button items.

The search button was created completely in the storyboard, but the category button was added programmatically using a segue identifier I set in the storyboard due to bar item limitations in the storyboard. First up, we have the code that corresponds with the buttons and then the screen shot. Remember this is for the right bar button items.

Button Initialized

```
self.categoryButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Categories", @"categories button") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(categoryButtonDidPress:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems arrayByAddingObject:self.categoryButtonItem];
```

Delegate methods for buttons

```
-(void) categoryButtonDidPress:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"categorySegueTable" sender:nil];
}

- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBarTable;

    self.searchBarTable.showsCancelButton = NO;

    if (self.searchBarTable.hidden == YES) {
        self.searchBarTable.hidden = NO;
    }
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [self.searchBarTable resignFirstResponder];
    self.searchBarTable.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    self.searchBarTable.showsCancelButton = YES;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding two buttons to the right side, you may find it easier to just add a `segmentedController` to the right with 2 segments (buttons) it will reduce the space and make it easier to manage.  Also, you may want to replace the word Categories with an icon to help compress the right side.

Comment: The icons for the buttons will come later on in the project. I'm student at Bloc.io, and I'm going for a minimum viable product at the moment. In other words, I just need to get the app to function with required user stories. I had a meeting with my mentor today, and he recommend I investigate the approach described. Any idea on how to slide in the current buttons in the navigation bar?

Comment: if you really want to animate the buttons in, your best bet would be to create a custom UIIView. Add your buttons to the view and then use a UIView Animation, something like `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`

Comment: Alright just so I understand what you're saying, essentially drag a view onto the view controller's navigation bar, and place the buttons within it? And then use the animation on the new view? If this is the case, UIBarButtonItem's will no longer work within the view. The buttons will have to be of type UIButton (which will limit the button system type). Anyway other ways you could think of using the current UIBarButtonItems?

Comment: That's the only other way I think it will be possible and it will still require a lot of trial and error as you will be fighting with the animation of the view itself as it animates within your Nav Controller stack. This is why I recommended using a segmentedController.

Comment: Final thought, if your app is for iOS 8 and above (or only for iPad) , you may consider using `UIPopoverController` as an alterative solution.

Comment: The popover is an awesome feature, and I experimented with it for a while, but I was needing a solution for the iPhone. I appreciate the help!